# richfaces calendar datePattern="yyyy/MM"

Tags: calendar, richfaces

I have problem with richfaces calendar. I want to see only year and month so i made datePattern="yyyy/MM", which works fine until i want to change date.

When i click on button and calendar pop up the current value disappear. If i don't select date the value is null. I tried to save old date in my bean but problem remains because when i open calendar it is always set to todays date.

Problem occur only when i don't put dd(days) in datePatern

```
<rich:calendar value="#{myBean.date}" datePatern="yyyy/MM" />
```

Tnx for help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer on richfaces forum so i will copy it also here

> I guess `rich:calendar` is not the right choice at you case although `rich:calendar` may be bound to probably any object type provided that you supply custom converter a day ordinal still should be supplied because it's a part of the date maybe you would do better with a `h:selectOneMenu` to specify a month and a `h:inputText` to define a year instead of "incomplete" `rich:calendar`